# Chrome extension Firebase in background script wont always load

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome extension with Google Firebase for authentication, I am using a web pack for building my project,
the Firebase is being used in the background script.

On the first init or when the script sleeps, Firebase returns null for the user and takes some time to read the current user so it returns null for the user.

The question is how can I load Firebase and then make the request so I won't get null?

Some snippets from my code

```
const getUser = async (): Promise<firebase.User> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { message: MESSAGES.getCurrentUser },
        (user: firebase.User) => {
          if (user) resolve(user);
          reject();
        }
      );
    });
```

and in the background script

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (request: Request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    switch (message) {
      case MESSAGES.logOut:
        logOut(sendResponse);
        break;
      case MESSAGES.getCurrentUser:
        getCurrentUser(sendResponse);
        break;
        break;
    }
    return true;
  }
);

const getCurrentUser = async (sendResponse: (response?: any) => void) => {
  
  const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
  sendResponse(user);
};
```

my manifest file

```
{
  "short_name": "",
  "name": "",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "identity", "downloads"],
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after quite the research found out that chrome shuts down the background script when it isn't in use and when you need the background script again it loads firebase from scratch and inside this load it checks the tokens and in this time firebase return null for the current user.
added some more logic for fixing this.

Comment: See also [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)