# service worker works only when DevTools (Console) is open

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm building chrome extension, and in background script I use:

```
chrome.alarms.create({periodInMinutes: 1})

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(() => {
  doSomeStuff();
});
```

I do it few times, and in the last call, I do `clearAll` alarms.

The problem which I encounter in this situation is:
My app works perfectly when Console is open.
But if I close my console in Chrome, my app stops working.

My opinion is that when I open Console to inspect `service worker` service worker is awake, but when I close it my service worker goes into idle (sleep) mode.

How to solve it?

Comment: The code you've shown isn't a problem. The problem is elsewhere. Service worker lives for 30 seconds so you should use chrome.storage.local to read/write the state in the event listener, not global variables. Alternatively, you can force the worker to live longer, see [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, I waited for your answer :) 
Everything what I read about chrome extensions was your answers. I will try to explain it better with more code.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm you got the point without looking into code.
I really relied on global variables for some counting in alarms.

Thank you a lot, you solved my problem.