# Creating Sandbox Window from Service Worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, sandbox, postmessage

I have a Chrome extension which requires a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/manifest/sandbox/) so that I can use a custom content security policy and also requires a Service Worker so I have a script running that is persistent. I would like the Service Worker to open a new (sandbox) window, and then be able to communicate with this sandbox by using `postMessage`.

I have tried three methods to create this window but none of them quite work for me:

- I tried `chrome.windows.create` which is able to create the window, but I don't have accese to `postMessage` (or at least I don't know how to access `postMessage` this way).
- I tried `window.open` which returns a `WindowProxy` object which I can call `postMessage` on. However this only works where the `window` context is available and this is not the case in Service Worker.
- I tried `clients.openWindow` however I ended up with an error "Not allowed to open a window".

Is there anyway to create a (sandboxed) window which allows me to use `postMessage` from a Service Worker in a chrome extension?

Comment: chrome.windows.create + navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage in the new page + self.onmessage inside the service worker. See also [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your suggestion, however when trying to do `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage` in the sandboxed page I get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'serviceWorker' property from 'Navigator': Service worker is disabled because the context is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.` According to [these docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/), `allow-same-origin` is not allowed in a sandbox's content security policy.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Put the sandboxed page inside an iframe. The container page (non-sandboxed) will use iframe.contentWindow.postMessage and window.onmessage for the response.

Comment: Did that work? If so, could someone post a proof of concept ?