# Chrome extension wtih manifestv3 - service worker doesn't wake up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a background srcipt defined like

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

and a content script

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
```

background does the usual

```
runtime.onMessage.addListener
```

and content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
```

But, at some rare situations (around 2-5% of users), the service worker stays inactive, despite a tab with youtube being open, so the sendMessage calls return nothing.

This is only solved with turning the extension off and back on.

Is there a way to wake up the service worker programmatically if it fell asleep? Is there a possible reason why service worker might not wake up? Uncaught exceptions, manifest settings?

I'm really lost here and it's extremely hard to debug, as it never happened to me during one month, and I can only debug it when a user agrees to have a call and share screen.

The extension has over a million users, but this is simply killing me.

The extension can be seen at https://github.com/Anarios/return-youtube-dislike/tree/main/Extensions/combined

This was confirmed to happen on the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1271154, ManifestV3 is still half-broken. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003493).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, yep looks like my case. And no good workaounds, from what it seems. Why did I chose manifest v3 :'(

Comment: @Anarion How did you go with this issue?

Comment: @Anarion Did you manage to find a solution/workaround?