# Chrome Extension performance difference - alarm + history vs storage + history

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My extension(manifest v3) needs to track the number of times a set of websites are visited either during the whole day or during certain time windows and then perform an action if the visit count exceeds a limit.

There are two ways I could think of implementing this:

1. **alarm + history**: Create an alarm that runs every 5 mins, search the history for the required websites and count the visits. If the count exceeds the limit perform an action
2. **storage + history**: Add a listener to `chrome.history.onVisited`. If the visited site is from the required list, increment the visit count in `storage`. If the storage count exceeds the limit perform an action

Which of the above approaches has least impact on Chrome's browsing performance? Or, is there any another api(s) that I can use to achieve the same?
I would like my extension to consume least amount of user's battery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1 the extension will do a lot of unnecessary work when the user isn't using the browser.

In 2 the extension's background script will restart more often if the user navigates a lot but makes pauses between navigating for more than the lifetime duration of the service worker (30 seconds by default), which is a typical interaction scenario.

In both cases the bigger inherent problem of ManifestV3 for an extension such as yours that observes user activity is not what the extension does itself, but the extremely huge overhead to restart the background worker, which is automatically terminated after 30 seconds since the last observed event (or 5 minutes if you use [waitUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)). Such pauses in user activity are typical when browsing/interacting so for many users the worker will restart hundreds of times a day. Starting the worker takes 50-100ms and stresses the CPU+memory+disk for the entire duration, while a typical time spent in a simple observation extension's code is just 1-2ms.

In other words, an extension that observes user activity, such as yours, is inherently 25-100 times less efficient in ManifestV3 than it would be in ManifestV2 with a persistent background script.

Solutions.

1. Prolong the service worker's lifetime to reduce the amount of its restarts as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269). To avoid wasting memory for users that keep the browser open without using it for hours you can dynamically adjust the lifetime duration by measuring and averaging intervals between the events or offer an option to set the duration in your extension UI. Hopefully, in the future the browser will do it automatically, but it may take years before this feature is actually implemented and even then it will still likely restart the background script way too often.
2. Use [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events with a URL filter for your sites so that the background script wakes up only when these specific URLs are visited. If the URLs are configured by the user, you will need to unregister the listener first (e.g. by making the listener a named global function), then register it with the new URL filter. You may still need to prolong the worker's lifetime if these URLs are visited a lot.

Comment: Does Chrome launch a new service worker every time an event listener is executed?

Comment: "...huge overhead to restart the background worker" - by background worker I believe you meant the service worker and not the background.js script.

Comment: As described in the answer, the worker is terminated after 30 seconds and starts again when a new event occurs. The worker is a generic term that often applies to the execution environment and the script that runs in the worker. The background script runs in the background service worker.