# chrome extension always show "service worker inactive" after browser restart if manifest is MV3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am using the latest chrome: Version 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build) (64-bit) on win 10 pro

when i install an extension all works fine.

when i close chrome and reopen, the extensions no long work.
the extensions tab shows for all extensions: "worker service (inactive)"

after click on the reload button of the extension all is ok.

i also tested it with:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/examples/hello-world

to make sure that this could be to some settings, i uninstalled chrome, removed all chrome files and reinstalled it.

the issue persists.

friends of mine do not seem to have this issue with the same chrome version.

any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

here the code:

```js
    "use strict";

async function sendRequest(request, sendResponse) {
  try {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const response = await fetch(request.url, request.options);
    const time = Date.now() - startTime;
    const body = await response.text();
    const headers = [...response.headers].map((el) => ({
      key: el[0],
      value: el[1],
    }));
    sendResponse({
      status: response.status,
      body,
      headers,
      time,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    sendResponse({
      err: err.message
    });
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("host", ({ host }) => {
    if (host === sender.tab.url) {
      if (request.type === "send-request") {
        sendRequest(request, sendResponse);
      } else if (request.type === "ping") {
        sendResponse();
      } else {
        console.log("bad request type", request.type);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("host not correct", host, sender.tab.url);
    }
  });
  // NOTE: return value required to keep port open for async response
  return true;
});

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(() => {
  console.info("service is up 2");
});

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((details) => {
  console.log('service is up');
});
```

Comment: The background script runs only when it's activated by some event e.g. in this case it's onInstall.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. the problem is that the background script does not react to events as long as it shows service inactive. chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((details) => {
  console.log('wake me up');
}); it seems that this listener is not triggered when a new web site is opened

Comment: i also tried: chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(() => {
  console.info("serviceis up 1");
});
});

Comment: The event listeners must be registered outside of other event listeners, not inside.

Comment: yes, i tried both inside the onInstall and globaly, no success

Comment: in background.js i have registered multiple listeners. none seem to wake up the service: chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener, chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate, chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.

Comment: [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029). Also make sure to reload the extension after editing. In case of further problems show your real code in the question, not in comments.

Comment: thanks. when service is inactive, click on service worker does not open the debugger if the worker is inactive.

Comment: It means the extension is broken, probably due to a bug in Chrome. Uninstall the extension and install it again.

Comment: thanks, tried install/uninstall 100x where can i report a bug ?

Comment: https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug. You can read more about it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271154#c52

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add an event handler for chrome.runtime.onStartup()

I've run into this issue where it always shows as inactive when starting Chrome and it went away with this small change, always starts active.

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener( () => {
    console.log(`onStartup()`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem here. Service Worker(inactive). yeah it's came to "inactive" in like 20 secs after you click refresh button on your extension.
And I seemed find a way to keep it running by somehow you can click the "Service Worker(inactive)" label then chrome will open a DevTools tab and you could see some logs printed from your background script. it worked well for me.The only point is DevTools tab needs to be opened forever.

Answer (score 0):

there is a "fix" for a probably very small subset of developers:
first go here and try all of that [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618136/persistent-service-worker-in-chrome-extension)
if this doesnt help (in my case it deactivated after moving the PC to hibernate)
and you use the service worker in a local environment where you can control the chrome instance you can do the following:

1. start chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=<someport>`
2. before an event where you want to ensure the servce worker is up (in my case it was sending a websocket event to the chrome extension)
3. import CDP from "chrome-remote-interface"
   const cdpOpts = {
   port: ,
   host: "0.0.0.0"
   }
   const scopeUrl="chrome-extension://pifdfbadejagoljdhnlmldpcnlfankli/" // replace with your own extension id which can be seen in the extension tab
   const client = await CDP(cdpOpts)
   await client.send("ServiceWorker.enable")
   await client.send("ServiceWorker.startWorker", {
   scopeURL
   })

this should reawaken the service worker through the remote debugging api