# How can I set global variables in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I work on a chrome extension which has a const user that is set in the first lines of the background.js, when I change its values and use them later in a different function they always return to their set values in the beginning.

I read online about hoisting and that it is to source of the problem but how can I avoid it so i can actually manipulate the variables and use them later on with no problem.

I also saw the use of globalThis but when i tried to call or set the values in the functions with globalThis it didn't work as well.

Here is my first lines of background.js:

```
var user={
connection:undefined,
id:"id",
username:"username",
room:["id","password","url","tabid","ishost"],
room_members:[],
in_room:false,
room_process:[false,"intervelId"],
current_tab:["url","id"]
```

}

I also tried working with globalThis when setting some of the values of user like showen here:

```
function connect(){
   globalThis.user.connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.3.16:8765'); 
   globalThis.user.connection.onopen = function(e) {
     globalThis.user.connection.send("get_id");
   };
   globalThis.user.connection.onmessage=function(event){
      let data=event.data.split(',');
    
      let temp_i=data[0]
      globalThis.user.id=temp_i;

      let temp_u=data[1]
      globalThis.user.username=temp_u;
    
    console.log("connection: ",user.id,",",user.username);
   };    
   
}
```

and for example if I got from the last function that user.id="Oak" when I try to recall the value in a different function like this:

```
function test(){
   console.log(user.id);
}
```

it shows "id" and not "Oak"

**EDIT**

I tried to use the storage.local by putting the var user in the onInstalled event of the program and then by having two functions I can get the current value of user out of the local storage and then update it as well.

here is my code:

first init of the var user:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
//opens welcome page
let url = chrome.runtime.getURL("htmls/hello.html");

let tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url });

//setting up the user var in chrome's local storage

chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {

    var user={
        connection:undefined,
        id:"id",
        username:"username",
        room:["id","password","url","tabid","ishost"],
        room_members:[],
        in_room:false,
        room_process:[false,"intervelId"],
        current_tab:["url","id"]
        }
    chrome.storage.local.set({userLocal: user}, function () {}); // save it in local.
    
});

//connect to server and recive id 
connect()
```

});

the two functions function:

```
function get_user(){
chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {
    var userLocal = result.userLocal;
    return userLocal;
});
```

}

```
function update_user(tmp_user){
chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {
    var userLocal = tmp_user;
    chrome.storage.local.set({userLocal: userLocal}, function () {}); // save it in local.
    return userLocal;
});
```

}

and for example if I use what I've written:

```
function connect(){

var user=get_user();

user.connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.3.16:8765'); //'ws://192.168.3.16:8765'
user=update_user(user);
```

}

I get this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'connection')"

Comment: Please include code as formatted text rather than pictures of text.

Comment: _"in the beginning"_: do you mean when you navigate to a new page?

Comment: @Andy, I meant when I recall the var it showes the same values that are set in the first lines. Even if I change their values somewhere between the two when I recall the value like user.id it shows "id" and not "Oak" (for example)

Comment: `const` or `let` doesn't put the variable into `globalThis` area.

Comment: Show the complete minimal code that demonstrates the problem ([MCVE](/help/mcve)).

Comment: @wOxxOm, when i turn it into var it dosent work also, plus I tried to show the MCVE but I cant narrow down the problem

Comment: @wOxxOm, what did you say before about the bg code rerunning after some time?

Comment: See and try [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a [background service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/) is loaded when it is needed, and unloaded when it goes idle. So, after a few seconds of being idle, the background script unloads itself, making you lose the changes you made to the user object.

You could save the user object in `chrome.storage.local`, and then read and modify from there. Something like this:

```
// background.js; "initial lines" =>

chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {
let userLocal = result.userLocal
if (userLocal === undefined) {
    // it means there was nothing before. This way you don't overwrite
    // the user object every time the backgorund.js loads.
    var user={
        connection:undefined,
        id:"id",
        username:"username",
        room:["id","password","url","tabid","ishost"],
        room_members:[],
        in_room:false,
        room_process:[false,"intervelId"],
        current_tab:["url","id"]
        }
    chrome.storage.local.set({userLocal: user}, function () {}); // save it in local.
}})
```

When you want to modify the user, you retrieve it from local and modify the result before saving it back in the `localStorage`.

```
// example of modifying a property =>

chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {
let userLocal = result.userLocal
if (userLocal !== undefined) {
    userLocal.connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.3.16:8765');
    // ...

    chrome.storage.local.set({userLocal: userLocal}, function () {}); // save it in local.
}})
```

You can also just read the user properties, without modifying them and saving them back to the `localStorage`.

############ EDIT:

because `chrome.storage.local` is asynchronous, try to transform you code like this:

```
async function get_user(){
    return new Promise(async function (res, rej) {
      chrome.storage.local.get(['userLocal'], async function (result) {
          var userLocal = result.userLocal;
          res(userLocal);
      });
    });
}

var user= await get_user(); // call it like this.
```

Comment: I have made a two functions: the first returns the user var and the second one updates the local storage and returns th updated var. When I use for example user.connection it says that it is undefined . I will put the code in the edit rn

Comment: @Oak_xo, that happens because `chrome.storage.local` is asynchronous. So you need to add a promise. Look at the edit I made.

Comment: and in your opinion where and when should I update the local storage's values of user?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you. What do you mean by 'where and when should I update the local storage's values of user'? Are you talking about specific files (contentScript.js, backgorund.js, ...)?