# Unable to get state value in when using long-lived connection in react base chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a `Popup.jsx` and a `Background.js`. The Popup creates a [long lived connection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect) to my background service worker.

I am maintaining a state in my `Popup.jsx`, which looks like this

```js
const [projectDetail, setProjectDetail] = useState({ projectCode: null })
```

The `useEffect` of my `Popup.jsx` looks like this,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'Background Connection' })
    port.onMessage.addListener(({ action, payload }) => {

      switch (action) {
        case ACTION.SET_PROJECT_DETAIL:
          setProjectDetail(payload);
          break;
  
        case ACTION.CHECK_STATE:
          console.log(projectDetail)
          break;
   
        
        default:
          break;
      }
  
    })
    port.postMessage({ action: ACTION.GET_PROJECT_DETAIL })
    return () => {
      port.disconnect()
    }
  }, [])
```

As you can see, after attaching the listener for `onMessage` on the `port` variable (which is defined outside the component scope), I am sending a message to the `Background.js` to get project detail. The `Background.js` responds back with as per the following code:

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  // console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 182 ~ chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener ~ port", port)

  port.onMessage.addListener(function ({ action, payload }) {

    if (action === ACTION.GET_PROJECT_DETAIL) {
       port.postMessage({ action: ACTION.SET_PROJECT_DETAIL, payload: { projectCode: "Some value"} })
    }

   // ...Removed more code for brevity

  });
});
```

Assume that I have a user interaction button which tells the `Background.js` to send a message to the `Popup.jsx` which matches the `case ACTION.CHECK_STATE:`, so evidently, I am expecting the `Popup.jsx` to console log the value `{projectCode: "Some value"}` as the state in the component has been updated (I have verified that it does by using `ReactDevTools`).

However, it prints `{ projectCode: null }` which was the initial state value.

**Note: the user interaction does not happen immediately after the component mounts, so its not that I am trying to get the state value immediately after I have set it.**

I am unable to get the updated state value inside the callback function for `addListener`. Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I guess it's because service worker terminates after 5 minutes, meaning you need to reconnect the port, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269) (see "If you already use ports").

Comment: @wOxxOm That could be the case, but even if the `CHECK_STATE` action gets triggered under 2 minutes, I still get old state value.

Comment: @wOxxOm I verified the case, even when the service worker is active, the result is the same.

Comment: So either the message wasn't received or setProjectDetail is bugged. You can set breakpoints there and see what actually happens. To open the popup's devtools, right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working was that the `port` variable was declared outside the functional component itself.

Initially, the `Popup.jsx` was defined like this,

```js
//...import statements

let port = null;
const Popup = () => {
  port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'Background Connection' });
  
  //...more code
}
```

Afterwards, I changed it into,

```js
//...import statements

const Popup = () => {
  let port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'Background Connection' });
  
  //...more code
}
```

I can't say specifically what exactly was the reason. However, it seems to me that it was scoping issue.