# Aborting fetch request in Chrome Extension background

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fetch, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, abortcontroller

With the change of Manifest V3 coming in for Chrome Extensions I'm updating all `XHR` requests to now use the `fetch` API as instructed.

The background of a Chrome Extension is now a Service Worker and can become inactive and the use of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is now being discouraged by chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#alarms)

I'm trying to work out how I can abort a long running request if now the background service worker can go to sleep using the code below;

```
function generateAbortingAboutController(timeoutInMilliseconds) {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();
    }, timeoutInMilliseconds);

    return controller;
}

function sendFetchRequest(type, url, data, contentType, dataType, onSuccess, onError) {

    const abortController = generateAbortingAboutController(100000);

    fetch(url, {
            method: type,
            body: data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": contentType
            },
            signal: abortController.signal
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw response;
            }
        })
        .then((json) => {
            onSuccess(json);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            if (e?.name === "AbortError") {
                return;
            }
            onError();
        });

    return abortController;
}
```

Is there a good practice on how to abort a long running request?

Comment: Service worker doesn't "go to sleep" or "become inactive" when its time is up. It is just terminated, along with all the network requests, timers, variables, etc. There's no need to cancel any of that explicitly. The default lifetime is 30 seconds. You can prolong it as shown in [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Where did you get your info about default lifetime of the service worker?

Comment: It's mentioned in some documentation probably. Also in the [source code](https://crsrc.org/third_party/blink/public/mojom/service_worker/service_worker.mojom;l=149;drc=3b34399247d1e59327251bcc9f55badd7e932197).