# Chrome Extension Manifest V3: Try to import socket-io.client but keeps receiving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm actually working on an chrome extension and I keep receiving this error while I'm importing the unpacked extension :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "socket.io-client". Relative references must start with either "/",
> "./", or "../".

I hope you could give me so advices and also answers as much as you can do for me. I've been searchin' here for a while but no one seems to have the same problem in TypeScript with the manifest v3 and the import problem for socket-io.client.

My manifest.json :

```json
{
  "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "default_locale": "fr",
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background/index.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "img/default_16.png",
      "32": "img/default_32.png",
      "48": "img/default_48.png",
      "128": "img/default_128.png",
      "256": "img/default_256.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.ts file :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "declaration": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {},
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

And also the 3 files that use the socket-io client
The index.ts in background folder :

```
import { start as socketIoStart } from './socket-io.js'
import { start as notificationStart } from "./notification.js";

socketIoStart();
notificationStart();
```

The socket-io.client.ts :

```
import { io } from "../dependencies/index.js";
import { handler } from "./handler.js";

/* Connects to the socket server */
const socket = io.connect("https://somewhere");

export const start = () => {
  socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Client connected");
  });
  socket.on("stream-status", (liveInformation) => {
    console.log("stream-status", liveInformation);
    handler(liveInformation);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
      // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
      socket.connect();
    }
    // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
  });
};
```

The dependancies index.ts:

```
export * as io from "socket.io-client";
```

Best Regards

Comment: It won't work in a service worker anyway.

Comment: why that @wOxxOm

Comment: I've done some research but none of it helps me out, did anyone have any clue?

Comment: You need to use a bundler such as webpack because there is no `socket.io-client` module in the browser. If you already do, then your config is incorrect. However, the much bigger problem is that service worker is terminated after inactivity, so your socket will be disconnected, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269) for workarounds.