# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest didn't work in manifest version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my chrome extension with manifest V2 I was using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` to get all requests of current tab. Here is

```js
const dataSet = {};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {

    if (details && details.url && details.type == "image") {
        if (!dataSet[tabId]) {
            dataSet[tabId] = new Set([]);
        }
        const currentSet = dataSet[tabId];
        currentSet.add(details.url);
    }


}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
});
```

I'm trying same code in manifest version 3 but event didn't triggers. Also I've tried this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71189817/) but it still didn't works.

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(){

   // this event is not being triggered
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){

   },{urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["main_frame"]});


},{
    url: [{hostContains:"domain"}]
});
```

Also tried to use `webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` but still `onBeforeRequest` didn't triggers

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((details) => {
    console.log('wake me up', details);
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        (details) => {
          console.log(details);
        },
        {
          urls: ['<all_urls>'],
         
        },
        
      );
  });
```

[Console output](https://prnt.sc/Qs1LA4SBdumb) of background page

Comment: Assuming you're using modern Chrome 108 which fixed webRequest wake-up bug, it can be another known bug in registration of the service worker. Try uninstalling the extension first, then install it again. Also note that console.log is cleared when the service worker is terminated so you need to look at it immediately.

Comment: Is this literally the code you're using? Because the first code block contains one closing curly bracket too many.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, my current chrome version is 108.0.5359.99.  I've also tried to put debugger in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest event, but still it didn't fired. I've also tried to woke up background page with alarms(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003493/6823766), I see that background is restarted, but still onBeforeRequest is not triggers

Comment: Did you open [background.js console?](/a/10258029)

Comment: @wOxxOm sure, I've opened background console, I can see other console logs from other events (chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate or chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated) https://prnt.sc/Qs1LA4SBdumb

Comment: 1) Don't use chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate listener, it's not necessary anymore and actually it may be the reason of the problem. 2) Try uninstalling the extension first, then install it again.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I've deleted and added extension, here is my code https://prnt.sc/iO_V7mDXCWtd  I can see 
   'wake me up' output of  onHistoryStateUpdated event, but still no output from onBeforeRequest

Comment: Don't use chrome.webNavigation listener, it's not necessary anymore and actually it may be the reason of the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried without any other event , just chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(....)  like in manifest V2 but it don't works (

Comment: Well, then it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Update: actually issue was related to hostPermission. We have to add `host_permissions: <all_urls>` in the manifest.json file