# session storage not preserved when chrome extension is updated

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a mv3 chrome extension in which I do not register chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable. I save some of my variables by chrome.storage.session.set to keep their values when service worker restarts. This works fine until my extension updates, all session storage is removed after update.

What I want to achieve is: either to preserve session storage across update, or make extension update happens only when browser restarts (in this case i dont need to save my variables any more).

Comment: What are extension updates? Does that mean reloading after modifying the files that make up the extension?

Comment: no, i mean update from web store

Comment: Is this a problem when you update the version of the app you publish on the chrome web store?

Comment: yes, session storage data is lost when extension updates from web store

Comment: Reloading the extension will initialize the session storage. I believe updating via the chrome web store is the same. Is there any reason why `chrome.storage.local` can't be used?

Comment: because i dont want to preserve these variables when browser restarts

Comment: You can initialize it with `chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener` when restarting the browser.

Comment: There's no solution other than [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269).

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all the comments above, these is no solution with non-persistent service worker.