# Question about extension service worker lifecycle

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

So I know there are a couple of standard service worker events and events in extension namespaces that my extension can react to and which can awake it. The question is when I use event listeners from 3rd party module (I'm using supabase specifically) will they wake the extension service worker? For example, in supabase we have `onAuthStateChange` event which triggers every time an auth event happens (i.e. refresh token's expired). But if my service worker's asleep? Will it be fired/will that kind of event wake the service worker?
Supabase listener's declared in the global scope of the service worker, of course.

MCVE: background.ts

```js
import supabase from 'API/client';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details: chrome.runtime.InstalledDetails) => {
  if (details.reason === 'update') {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ lastSyncSnapshot: null });
  }
});

supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event: any, session: any) => {
  if (event == 'TOKEN_REFRESHED') {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ session: session });
  }
});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm it is actually at the top of the service worker, I register it synchronously. so there shouldn't be any issues in that case?

Comment: @wOxxOm take a look once more please if it's more clear now. but from what I can experience and see atm it doesn't work. as soon as SW falls asleep I don't receive any realtime updates from supabase.

Comment: Yes, only `chrome` events and SW messaging/fetch events wake the SW up. See [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)