# In chrome extension, can I query data from a webpage before navigation?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, browser, web-applications, navigation

I develop a Chrome extension where I capture some data from the user journey on a website. The data is cached in a local variable of the content script added to the webpage. The background script (service worker) queries data from the content script when the user clicks a button in the extension popup.

But the website is not fully a single-page application (SPA) and therefore whenever there is a page navigation, the cached data is lost and I cannot build the whole journey.

**Question:**
Is there a way, I can get the data cached on the page before navigation and send it back to the navigated page?

Few considerations:

1. The size of data is huge and might exceed the storage limits of browser local storage or session storage, i.e. 5MB.
2. I persist the data in content script instead of background script for efficiency as the flux rate of data is high and there can be multiple such tabs open at a time.

Comment: You'll have to save the data in chrome.storage or in the service worker, anything else like onbeforeunload + sendMessage won't be reliable, AFAIK.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried onbeforeunload + chrome.storage.local.set but even that is not reliable. Saving to chrome.storage on every data event seems too expensive.

Comment: Try the other thing I suggested, which is to save the data in the service worker. See also [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)