# Should content-script use chrome.alarms or setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, messaging

When I write content-script to send msg to service-worker every X time, should I use `chrome.alarms` or `setInterval`?

This is what I wrote:

`content-script.js`

```js
const send = (async () => {
  try {   
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "ping" });
    console.log(response)
  } catch {
    console.log("problem")
  }
});

setInterval(send, 1000) // or chrome.alarms...
```

`background.js`

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.msg)
    sendResponse({ msg: "pong" })
  }
);
```

Comment: Is that what you wrote working? if yes, then what's your problem? If no, what's the error? I don't really understand your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it looks like it's working, but I'm not sure that using setInterval is the correct way, and maybe it will be a problem with more complex code.

Comment: @Nati - Like the Community Bot wrote, we need more information about yout extension. We can't tell you if chrome.alarms or setInterval is better suited to your extension because we know nothing about it. Please tell us what your extension does, and why the content script needs to send messages to the service worker.

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.alarms. Note that the web page can clear your interval, so a more reliable method is to use the timer inside the service worker, see also [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269)

Comment: @wOxxOm But how to trigger a function in content script from service worker using chrome.alarms? AFAIK, service worker cannot send a message to content script without getting a message first from it...

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.sendMessage.