# Chrome extension MV3: persistent service worker die after wake up from hibernation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, hibernation

I'm using this solution by wOxxOm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618136/persistent-service-worker-in-chrome-extension/) to keep the service worker alive in my chrome extension (manifest v3).

I used the offscreen solution because I use win7 so I can only use chrome v109. it works very well, but when the PC hibernate then wake up, the service worker will restart with a probability of 50%. for example if I hibernate after 10s and wake up after 10s then the SW will restart always...

This problem does not happen in my tests when I use background scripts using manifest v2 with `"persistent" : true`

Is there something I can do to make the SW persistent (not restart after hibernation) as in MV2?

I tested other solutions but none worked, for example I discovered that I can make the SW persistent using alarms too:

```js
// keep SW alive for 30s
// self.serviceWorker.postMessage('test')

// this will keep SW alive for 5min then chrome will kill it, to prevent this kill we will run alarm every 4min  
// we run setInterval every 20s to prevent SW sleep in the first minute
setInterval(()=>{self.serviceWorker.postMessage('test');console.log("___________postMessage every 20 seconds");},20000);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.alarms.create('keepAlive', { periodInMinutes: 4 });
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((info) => {
  if (info.name === 'keepAlive') {
    self.serviceWorker.postMessage('test');
    console.log("++++++++++++alarm every 4 min");
  }
});
```

But it did not solve the hibernation problem too. I'm out of ideas, any idea please?

is this problem solved in newer chrome versions? i have only win7 i cannot test the newer chrome versions unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome that is not related to the persistency trick: Chrome apparently adds the hibernation time to the internal idle timer of the service worker, so it becomes larger than 30 seconds. In other words the same will happen even without the persistency trick if you suspend the PC immediately after any `chrome` API event received by the service worker, wait for more than 30 seconds, resume the PC.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks to God that i got an answer from you, i came here hoping to get an answer specially from you because you are the only faithful person i know who best understand the chrome internals. so i can do nothing except be prepared for this SW's restarts, thank you very much sir.

Comment: @wOxxOm please do you think that my method using alarms is fine to use? because it is easier than using offscreen, but i m afraid that alarm method have bugs i do not know

Comment: I'd simply use the first method ("bug exploit") because Chrome team apparently can't admit it's a bug (and I've pressed them quite persistently in public), so it won't be fixed for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @wOxxOm
 1- unfortunately the "bug exploit" was introduced in chrome v110 as you said, i need persistency in v109. please if you were in my place which one you will choose, offscreen or alarms? 

2- and does the "bug exploit" in v110 solves the hibernation problem?

Comment: I guess, offscreen, because it's truely persistent, at least for the foreseeable future.

Comment: See also https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6759 and try [scheduler.postTask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Scheduler/postTask).

Comment: @wOxxOm can you please explain the use case of postTask? i could not understand how it can prevent the SW restart, it seems that it serves for  deferring low priority work during loading (which is very nice and it will help me a lot, i never heard about it). but if you mean that it can solve the SW restart then i could not find any info about how it can be used for this. please correct me.

Comment: Try using it instead of setInterval with the bug exploit example.

Comment: @wOxxOm it did not work, `SW` died after 30s, i tested `delay: 25000` and `45000`,  i did:
```const keepAlive = () => scheduler.postTask(() => {chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo()}, { delay: 25000 });
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(keepAlive);
keepAlive();```